# How to get HDMI port to output to monitor?

Tags: 12.04, hdmi

I have an external Dell P2412H monitor attached to the HDMI port of my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04.

`xrandr` reports:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 256mm x 144mm
1366x768 60.0*+
1360x768 59.8 60.0 
1024x768 60.0 
800x600 60.3 56.2 
640x480 59.9 
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

It looks like the it does not recognise the monitor attached.

This is what `xrandr` reports when connected via VGA:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 256mm x 144mm
1366x768 60.0*+
1360x768 59.8 60.0 
1024x768 60.0 
800x600 60.3 56.2 
640x480 59.9 
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
1920x1080 60.0*+
1280x1024 75.0 60.0 
1152x864 75.0 
1024x768 75.1 60.0 
800x600 75.0 60.3 
640x480 75.0 60.0 
720x400 70.1 
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Please any ideas would be useful. Please keep in mind that I'm very new to Ubuntu, so I'd prefer some step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Please add the model of your laptop, and the output from the command `lshw -c display`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The [Dell P2412H](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-p2412h/pd) does not have HDMI connectivity. Please explain how you connected the monitor. Also, do you have any information about whether this works in Windows (in case you're running dual-boot)?